# Python: When catching a generic (any) exception, how do I store the exception name in a variable?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I know I can store an exception name in a variable with this syntax:

```
try:
    code
except TypeError as e:
    logger.error(e)
except NameError as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

How do I do the same for the generic `except:` message? I assume that this (which is the general idea) won't work:

```
try:
    code
except as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

Comment: Never try to catch a bare `except` as it will even stop catching rogue programs with CTRL-C.

Answer (score 3):

You can you use type(e).__name__ to capture the name of any error you encounter, and access the message as you a normal variable, with e.message. All the built in errors (indexError, TypeError, etc.) are children of the class Exception, so they will be picked up. to save it as a variable named 'err':

```
try:
   code
except Exception as e:
   err = type(e).__name__
   message = e.message
```

This will save the error type of any exception of the base python type Exception that you run into, using the built in __name__ variable

Comment: Should I catch BaseException too (for built-in rather than user-defined exceptions), as another comment suggested?

Comment: you can read about it more in depth in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html), but Exception will cover BaseException, as well as user created errors, which should be created as an Exception object. TL;DR: Exception will cover all built-in, non system exiting errors

Answer (score 3):

`BaseException` is the broadest type you can catch:

```
try:
    # some code
except BaseException as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to catch `Exception`:

```
import logging

try:
    code
except TypeError as e:
    logger.error(e)
except NameError as e:
    logger.error(e)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

Comment: If you're handling them all the same way, you might as well just catch `Exception`, as it includes the others.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with Python 2, where old-style classes aren't caught by `except Exception` or `except BaseException`. I solved it by using `sys.exc_info` to access the current exception:

```
import sys

try:
    code
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    logging.error(e)
```